# Why don't numpy arrays remember that they've been sorted?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

This probably isn't a question specific to numpy but the question occurred to me was when I was trying to optimize a piece of code utilizing numpy arrays and I think it's a good example case.

My question is why numpy arrays don't "remember" whether they have been sorted or not. Wouldn't this would an obvious opportunity to improve performance when checking conditions expressed by the standard relational operators?

To illustrate, instantiate an explicitly unsorted array.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(30000)

# unsorted array
y = np.random.choice(x, x.size, replace=False)
```

Then test a simple `>` conditional ...

```
%timeit y > 20
# 15.1 µs ± 870 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit y > 25000
# 14.8 µs ± 349 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

This takes about the same time for any value, as you would expect (it has to check condition against every value in the array).

However, if we explicitly sort the array and then run the same test...

```
y.sort()
%timeit y > 20
# 14.8 µs ± 737 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit y > 25000
# 14.8 µs ± 515 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The results are more or less the same, which suggests the condition is still being checked against every value in the array.

It seems to me that if numpy arrays had a boolean attribute to indicate if the array has been explicitly sorted or not, then there would be an opportunity for performance gains by running something like this:

```
def sorted_greater_than(arr, z):
    l = len(arr)
    for i,v in enumerate(arr):
        if v > z:
            return np.array([False]*i + [True]*(l-i))
    return np.full(l,False)
```

I.e. we know every value after i is greater than the value at i so if the value at i is greater than z then all the other values after i are also greater than z (and similarly for the other operators).

I am of course not suggesting that numpy has been poorly optimized, I am just wondering what I'm missing here? Is there something logically inconsistent about the notion of an object "remembering" if it has been sorted?

Comment: That'd add a whole bunch of overhead for something that can and should be handled by the programmer when needed.

Comment: *which suggests the condition is still being checked against every value in the array* is **exactly** what `y>20` is designed to do. Your `sorted(arr, z)` function seems to do something else.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica is it really that much more overhead? Seems like it would still be a net performance gain but perhaps not

Comment: Exactly. Why don't they remember they if are sorted? Why don't they remember they if are reverse sorted? Why don't they remember if they are positive? Why don't they remember they if are negative? Why don't they remember if they are squares? Why don't they remember if they are cubes? Why don't they remember if they are fibonacci sequence? Why don't they...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I would say that's a bit disingenuous. Sorting and conditionals of relational operators are 2 of the most common operations on arrays. It's not THAT outlandish to suggest there might be efficiency gains by compromising their independence

Comment: @tofd I don't see how that is disingenuous. Sorting and conditionals might be "2 of the most common operations" *for you*. That doesn't mean that conditionals on sorted arrays are particularly common overall to warrant paying a price on every single array out there.

Comment: I would think sorting an array is a quite *uncommon* operation. Arrays are designed to facilitate repeated operations on their elements; ordering isn't typically a concern.

Comment: Either way, it's just not clear to me what kind of answer you expect. There is nothing to "miss" here other than that no-one found the maintenance and runtime cost worth it.

Comment: @chepner that would genuinely surprise me considering the kind of things that I think numpy is typically used for but you could be right. Perhaps I'm assuming generality where there is none.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi great, thank you for your input :)

Comment: Also, it's trivial to modify an array in a way that changes the value of `y > 20` while leaving it sorted. Consider `y = np.array([1,2,3])`; `y > 20` is `[False, False, False]`, but after `y += 20` the array is still sorted and `y > 20 == [True, True, True]`.

Comment: @chepner sure it changes the conditional mask but if you know it's still sorted (i.e. you know addition doesn't change the value of the "sorted" attribute) you can still exit the loop when (and if) the condition passes, saving you going through the rest of the array. I'm just a bit surprised that the minimal overhead of checking a boolean class attribute is considered too much of a cost.

Comment: Keep in mind that numpy is optimized for *vectorized* operations. Your algorithm to exploit sortedness is *iterative*. The former can much better exploit the hardware. Even if that means you *logically* perform less operations (but still on average n/2), the brute speed advantage of vectorization using naive comparison (on average only twice as many operations) will outshine it in all but the most skewed situations.

Comment: @tofd `y > 20` doesn't have a conditional exit. It's an element-wise comparison to `20`, not a filter that determines where the first element that is/isn't greater than 20 is found.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi fair point, i don't know enough about the low level mechanics of vectorization to completely understand where the brute speed advantage comes from, but I guess it is something to do with asynchronous operations. I was just musing on the fact that theoretically at least there seems to be more scope for optimization based on the logical implications of previous operations on an array

Comment: @chepner well yes I realize that - that is exactly the gist of my question: why it doesn't have a conditional exit

Comment: The TLDR is that a CPU can operate on several values at once, provided the operation is the same. That is what vectorization does. In contrast, iteration explicitly works on one value after the other.

Comment: As mentioned `numpy` compiled methods were, for the most part written, to operate on the whole array without implied order.  That's the most general purpose case.  What you are proposing is some sort of short circuiting.  I believe that is done for a few values with functions like `np.max`.  But if you need this for other cases, look into using `numba`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, most, if not all of `numpy's` speed comes from using compiled code, with efficient iteration through the elements of the array (with strides etc).  While `numpy` has a lot of `no-gil` macros, low level "vectorization/multiprocessing" will be used only if the `C` compiler implements it.

Comment: @hpaulj: For a long time, I thought NumPy core operations didn't use any hardware vectorization, but it turns out I was completely overlooking the files where it was implemented. Particularly [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.20.1/numpy/core/src/umath/simd.inc.src), though recent code reorganization has introduced a lot more SIMD-related files.

Comment: Another consideration is that arrays are multidimensional.  They could be sorted on one axis, but not all.  The kind of short circuiting that you describe becomes more complicated when each row is sorted, or each column, but the array as a whole is not.

Comment: @hpaulj Sorting a multidimensional array is only possible along one axis so isn't just a matter of applying the same logic to multiple one-dimensional arrays rather than just one..?

Answer (score 0):

While it may improve performance when you need to know if the lists/arrays are sorted, it would slow down every manipulation you do on the list such as appending or inserting elements, replacing subsets.  The tradeoff is going to be really bad for the most frequent use cases (which are not related to the sorted states).

At best, a list could retain the fact that it hasn't been changed since the last sort but even that would add extra memory that would almost never be needed.

If you need a list that retains its sorted state, you could create a class of you own and manage that state within it. (it may be a good exercise to understand the amount of overhead involved).

Comment: A number of comments mention the additional overhead, but to me it seems that the only additional overhead is a boolean attribute (i.e. ```array.sorted```) that is checked at every array operation (and possibly switched on/off depending on the logical implications of the particular operation). If ```array.sorted``` is False, then operations would be performed as normal. Isn't this the absolute minimum amount of additional overhead that is possible in programming?

Comment: That's just the memory overhead, there is also processing.  To maintain word alignment in memory a simple boolean would likely consume 8 bytes per list (on a 64bit system). Designer of a programming language have to make it as fast as possible so every little bit counts.  Just as an example, updating a sorted flag on a large list could cause a page fault, which in turn causes the process to lose the rest of its time slot for a one in a million use case (they just won't have that)

Comment: I guess to me it still seems to be a worthwhile cost/benefit relative to the other attributes that numpy arrays maintain. But it seems I am in the minority (maybe I use numpy for different purposes compared with the average user). Thanks for the extra detail though.

Comment: Also several people suggested to make my own class, but unless the numpy C backend is modified directly it's not going to help much except in a very limited number of cases.